# Tensorflow: create y-indices from class labels

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning

I have class labels as:

```
y = ["class1", "class2", "class3"]
```

for using them in a model, I want to convert these classes to y_indices as *1, 2* with methods of keras and/or tensorflow2.0.

What I am doing currently is:

```
tokenizer = tf.keras.preprocessing.text.Tokenizer()
tokenizer.fit_on_texts(y)
y_train = tokenizer.texts_to_sequences(y)
```

I know that the tokenizer is kind of misused here. Are there better and smaller solutions for converting class labels to indices?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use a Tokenizer for this because the Tokenizer indexing starts at 1, and not 0. You can use `tf.where`:

```
import tensorflow as tf

y = ['class3', 'class1', 'class1', 'class2', 'class3', 'class1', 'class2']

names = ["class1", "class2", "class3"]

labeler = lambda x: tf.where(tf.equal(x, names))

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(y).map(labeler)

next(iter(dataset))
```

```
<tf.Tensor: shape=(1, 1), dtype=int64, numpy=array([[2]], dtype=int64)>
```

If you want to do it on a list or Numpy array you can use Scikit-Learn:

```
from sklearn.preprocessing import LabelEncoder

le = LabelEncoder()
    
le.fit_transform(y)
```

```
array([2, 0, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1], dtype=int64)
```

As I said previously, your implementation started indexing at 1:

```
[[2], [1], [1], [3], [2], [1], [3]]
```

This crashes Keras when it measures loss and metrics. It will return `nan` because you'll have three final neurons, but targets srtating from the 2nd index to the 4th. **tl;dr** don't use indexing that starts at 1 with Keras.

Comment: I cheated by using 4 output neurons for a small case. However, this is a very useful information. Thank you for your answer!